# undefined method `name' for #<User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i have the titled error when i go to http://localhost:3000/users/new
fill out the form to create user and click the button "create user"

My table consists of first_name, last_name, email, and password

I tried to fix if for half an hour. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.order(:email)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb 
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User #{@user.email} was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your model and views please.

Comment: There is no field like `name` you have `first_name, last_name`

Comment: Yes my model looked like this  validates :name presence: true, uniqueness: true , it should of looked like this  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

Answer (score 5):

You might have included a presence validation in you Model file

validates :name, presence :true

when it doesnt really exist as column

Answer (score 3):

You probably have something like:

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

in your form. It's incorrect, since you don't have `name` column in `users` table, instead, you have `first_name` and `last_name` columns.